# How to delete IMAP mail with fetchmail / procmail

Tags: imap, procmail, fetchmail

I use `fetchmail` with `imap` protocol to upload emails from a mail server, and pipe them in `procmail`. I do this with the following command:

```
fetchmail -f /home/$USER/.fetchmailrc --ssl -t 100 -d 240 -s -m "/usr/bin/procmail /home/$USER/.procmailrc "
```

The `.fetchmailrc` is as follows:

```
poll imap.my_email_server.com protocol IMAP
user "user@email_server.com" with password "myPassword" is "user@email_server.com" here keep
```

The .procmailrc is the following :

```
:0: 
* ^Subject: someSubject
{
  :0 c
  |  $BIN/parse_email
  :0 c
  $HOME/posnav
  :0 
  /dev/null
}
```

Everything works fine but how can i make the last command (here I push the email to /dev/null just to show the purpose) delete the email *on the server* from where I have fetched the emails ?

Comment: Procmail is designed to process local mail. That's also why you need fetchmail in the 1st place. Even an external helper would likely cause issues b/c IMAP expects to operate uninterrupted. Look at other tools. I never used them but maybe [imapfilter](https://github.com/lefcha/imapfilter) & similar?

Comment: There is a simple and basically unmaintained tool [`procimap`](https://github.com/tripleee/procimap) which I used for many years, but it inherits some pesky design warts from the code it's forked from, and adds some of its own. Needless to say (because it's already explained in the previous comment) Procmail itself has no capabilities to talk to an IMAP server.

Comment: As an aside, saving with `:0c` to one folder only to then deliver to `/dev/null` is rather roundabout. Simply lose the `c` flag on the first delivering recipe instead.

Comment: The lock on the braces is also incorrect, and the `c` on the pipe looks highly dubious, though it is of course possible that it is correct if the `parse_email` action is performed for side effects, and cannot be made to also save the messate somewhere.

Comment: AFAIK, this is beyond the capabilities of both procmail and fetchmail. What I would do it finding or developping another tool that will receive a list of messages and will connect to the  IMAP server (using the .fetcmailrc file to avoid key duplication) and ask for deletion of the messages.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete the mail on the server, you have to tell fetchmail to do that.

But, you explicitly told fetchmail to keep the message on the server by including the keyword "keep" in the run control file.

Change it to "no keep":

```
poll imap.my_email_server.com protocol IMAP
user "user@email_server.com" with password "myPassword" is "user@email_server.com" here no keep
```

Comment: I think that this is not what the OP wants. I think the aim is to delete the messages _after reading and considering useless_.